# How to attach multiple files to a VF page using one button

Tags: visualforce, attachment

Can any one suggest if there is any package or useful link for this.

As of now, I have a button on my visualforce page, where I can upload one document. If i select another document again, the 1st one is over writed. So, here can any one suggest how to add multiple attachments using one button. Like in gmail, we add attachments.

I am just looking for useful link. As far I have searched, I wasn;'t able to find. I will be able to write the code, based on the suggested link or package.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

There is no visualforce native solution to this. But you can use HTML5 to achieve this.

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" onchange="uploadFiles(this);"/>
```

and catch the files in `input.files` array in JavaScript.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function uploadFiles(input)
        {
            for(var i =0; i<input.files.length; i++)
            {           
                var filesizeInBytes = input.files[i].size;
                var filename = input.files[i].name;
                console.log("File name is : "+input.files[i].name+" and  size : "+input.files[i].size+" Bytes");                    
            }           
        }

    </script>
```

You can utilize [this blog](https://forceadventure.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/uploading-attachments-to-salesforce-using-javascript-remoting/) to read the files uploaded and send to apex controller.

Comment: Santanu, this working when i add multiple files at a time. If i select one file and after selecting the first one, if select 2nd one in another instance then 1st one is lost. Can you suggest how to overcome this?

Comment: Not sure, but I think you can keep an array declared outside `uploadFiles` function and dump all items from input.files into that.. so in a way, that array will keep all the files selected in different instances.

Comment: Use the script on this blog to bypass the limit http://kevansfdc.blogspot.com/2017/05/upload-attachment-to-salesforce-without.html

Comment: Hi Santanu how can i get the files content once the file is passed to apex controller not through ajax.Is there other way around.

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal, that depends upon how you are sending the file body to apex. I would suggest you to open a new question about it and we should be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out venky in the official dev forum :
[developer forum](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AbocIAC)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this link, but it consist of multiple buttons for multiple attachments.